# React BrowserRouter Changes URL but Component doesn't Render

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement the React **BrowserRouter** in my App. The URL changes but the component never loads and there are no errors in the console.

This is a *VS Web Application using React*.

**App.js**

```
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
    import MainApp from './components/MainApp';
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
    import Home from './components/Home/Home';
    import UserGrid from './components/UserGrid/UserGrid';
    
    export default class App extends Component {
        render() {
            return <BrowserRouter>
                <MainApp>
                    <route exact path="/" Component={{Home}}/>
                    <route path="/usergrid" Component={{UserGrid}}/>
                </MainApp>
                </BrowserRouter>;
        }
    }
```

**Home.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    const Link = require('react-router-dom').Link
    
    export default class Home extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
    
                    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
                    <div>
                            <div><Link to='/usergrid'>Go to Users</Link> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    );
        }
    
    }
```

**UserGrid.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Col, Container, Row } from 'reactstrap';
    import DataTable from '../UserForm/DataTable';
    import RegistrationModal from '../UserForm/RegistrationModal';
    import { USERS_API_URL } from '../../constants';
    
    ....
    export default class UserGrid extends React.Component {
    render() {
            return <Container style={{ paddingTop: "100px" }}>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <h3>Users</h3>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
    ...
    }
    }
    
    }
```

Initially when I created the project the BrowserRouter was in index.js please let me know if I should move it back. Ultimately I want a Login page and of course application routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is it normal that you import `Route` and use `route` in lowercase ?
2. Is it normal that you put `{{ }}` instead of `{ }` in `{{Home}}` and `{{UserGrid}}` below ?
3. I don't know if it's a case-sensitive issue too, but you can try `component` in lowercase for `Component={Home} Component={UserGrid}`

Then, this :

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
    
<route exact path="/" Component={{Home}}/>
<route path="/usergrid" Component={{UserGrid}}/>
```

would become :

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
    
<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
<Route path="/usergrid" component={UserGrid}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Component expects the component to be passed directly, not as an object. Route should be with upper case, only native react components can be declared with lowercase.

Fix the following things in your code and try if it works,

```
 import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
 import MainApp from './components/MainApp';
 import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
 import Home from './components/Home/Home';
 import UserGrid from './components/UserGrid/UserGrid';
    
    /* App.js */ 
    export default class App extends Component {
         render() {
             return <BrowserRouter>
                 <MainApp>
                     <Route exact path="/" Component={Home}/> /* <== */
                     <Route path="/usergrid" Component={UserGrid}/> /* <== */
                 </MainApp>
               </BrowserRouter>;
            }
        }
    
    /* Home.js */
    import React from 'react';
    import {Link} from 'react-router-dom
        //const Link = require('react-router-dom').Link  /* Delete */
        
        export default class Home extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
        
                        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
                        <div>
                                <div><Link to='/usergrid'>Go to Users</Link> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        );
            }
        
        }
```